# foreach chart in powerpoint slide ?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have 2 questions.

1.
I have VS2010 with Frameowrk 3.5 and need to lift some data and text and update some existing Powerpoint files. What would be the best approach ? I'm new to VSTO but have been using C# for quite a while.

2.
I've been testing with the Interop libraries (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint)
So I need to open a powerpoint and change some text in all slides and charts. Slides and sahapes are no problem but charts seem to be a problem. There doesn't seem to be a charts collection and 
    if (shape.Type == Office.MsoShapeType.msoChart) 
returns false.

I've done this previously in VBA and used the code below

```
For Each chtChart In sht.ChartObjects
        chtChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Replace    (chtChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text, "{month}", strCurrent,    VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare)
Next chtChart
```

I just really want to do the same.

Am I missing something really obvious ?

Any pointers gratefully received.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of charts you might run across in PPT.  Ignoring the old MSGraph charts, you might find charts that the user has added using Insert | Chart.

These will be shapes of .Type = 3 (msoChart).  Here's an example of how you get at the chart and/or chart data for these:

```
Sub ShowChartData()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim oData As ChartData

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim sTemp As String

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

Set oCht = oSh.Chart
oCht.ChartData.Activate
Set oData = oCht.ChartData

For x = 1 To 4
    For y = 1 To 4
        sTemp = sTemp & oData.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y) & vbTab
    Next    ' y/cell
    Debug.Print sTemp
    sTemp = ""
Next ' x/row

' do this to get rid of visible worksheet
oData.Workbook.Close

Set oData = Nothing
Set oCht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Charts might also be linked or embedded objects copy/pasted from Excel.

Comment: Thanks Steve - useful info - I have found the correct proprty for Chart title in Powerpoint. It's shape.Chart.ChartTitle.Text